# Bounty Rewards Increase by Torment?

Tags: diablo-iii

Do you get more or less act reagents (corrupted angel flesh, westmarch holy water etc) depending on the torment level?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> There is never more than 1 of these materials in a cache for characters below level 70. Above that point the number of materials increases with higher difficulty levels.
>
> - 3 Materials: Normal - Master
> - 6 Materials: Torment 1 - Torment 6.
> - 8 Materials: Torment 7 - Torment 9.
> - 10 Materials: Torment 10.
> - 12 Materials: Torment 11.
> - 14 Materials: Torment 12.
> - 16 Materials: Torment 13.
>
> The game limits your cache mats (including bonus caches) to 1 when below level 70, regardless of difficulty.

[Source 1](http://www.diablowiki.net/Horadric_Cache_materials), [Source 2](http://d3resource.com/difficulties/index.php?1)

Comment: This seems slightly off.  I consistently get a total of 3 when doing bonus acts on Master.  (I think it's 2 + a bonus of 1 for Master?)

Comment: I second that doubt. Before 70, I was getting 3 per bonus act on Hard and Master, and 4 per act on Torment I. Didn't play on 70 yet.

Comment: It's highly likely that this information is based on lv70 characters and it might not be entirely accurate for characters below 70. In my experience, from what I can remember, the information seems pretty accurate for lv70 characters.

Comment: I get 3 items when running bounties on T3.

Comment: @DavidYell I updated the answer with more up-to-date info, the old info was based on PTR and there were some changes since.

Comment: Yey, now it's accurate about the main cache. But first paragraph now contradicts the last ones - is it below 69 or 65? Is it max 1 from any cache or only main one?

Comment: @OrcJMR good catch, it must be a mistake on the diablowiki. I can't confirm 100%, but it only makes sense that the 1 material limit is below 70, not 65. I also bolded the part where it says that the bonus cache *always* drops as many as it would for the difficulty level, regardless of level.

Comment: This answer is out-of-date. Could you please provide information for T11-T13?

Comment: @StupidOne updated

Answer (score 6):

For 2.4.2 (Season 7):

[image: Difficulty Chart]

Source: http://d3resource.com/difficulties/

**Here's the cache materials specifically (Reg + Bonus):**

- Normal-Master: 2 + 1
- T1-T6: 3 + 3
- T7-T9: 4 + 4
- T10: 5 + 5
- T11: 6 + 6
- T12: 7 + 7
- T13: 8 + 8